# Function to Automatically set number of corresponding records in one table as default value in second table

Tags: postgresql

I'm kind of stuck here. I'll try to keep it simple.

I have two tables.

1. **Products** (product_id, number_of_reviews, ...)
2. **Reviews** (main_product_id, review, ...)

*main_product_id* in Reviews table is the foreign key referencing *product_id* of Products table.

I need that the *number_of_reviews* column should automatically update to the number of reviews for that *product_id* present in the Reviews table. Match can be made by comparing *product_id* with *main_product_id*.

I know that I can use count to get number of reviews using this sql statement like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reviews WHERE main_product_id = 'exampleid1'
```

Here exampleid1 should be product_id from products table.

But **how do I create the function that I can call for DEFAULT in column number_of_reviews?** Function that automatically takes the product_id from current row and passes it to that select statement and return the number of reviews...

I'm just so stuck here from hours, did a lot of searching but I can't figure it out.

It is my first time asking a question here on stackoverflow and my first time I'm taking interest in coding. PERN stack to be specific.
(I didn't like code for more than 6 years but now finally i built some interest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked for me - Thanks to the demo and code provided by @belayer

```
create or replace function record_a_review_air()
      returns trigger 
      language plpgsql 
as $$
begin 
    update products 
    set n_reviews = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reviews WHERE main_prod_id = prod_id)
    where prod_id = coalesce(new.main_prod_id, old.main_prod_id);
    return new;
end;
$$;

create trigger reviews_air
      after insert or delete or update of rev_id, main_prod_id, review
      on reviews
      for each row 
      execute function record_a_review_air();
```

(**I updated the answer to add the new code that works for me on events(insert, update, delete)** )

Comment: A couple issues. It will not work for update of product id, for that you need to update new.product_id (as use have) and update old.product_id (which you do not have). If just the column `review` is updated this is unnecessary as the number of reviews does not change. See [trigger functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/plpgsql-trigger.html) for a list of predefined parameters availability.

Comment: Hmm, Not sure if I understand you completely but when I test it, it works fine for my use case. Like when I update any row of reviews table or when I insert new row in reviews table, then the reviews column of products table gets automatically updated with correct data. Correct data which is the number of reviews for the corresponding product id.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I've looked at trigger functions and guess I need to change something to make it work for DELETE as well. It doesn't update products table when I delete a record in reviews table. In my code I made it to fire after insert, update and delete. but for delete I think I need to use old parameter somehow?

Comment: I've updated the answer with new code that works for delete as well. Testing shows it works fine for me. Let me know if anything is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First off this is actually a bad plan, you are saving a value the can easily be calculated. However, it seems quite common even though it often leads to complications. The *function* you need is a `trigger`; more specifically a trigger function and a trigger on `reviews`. (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=7bc0c518b8127887665ff8efe31a6aeb))

```
create or replace function record_a_review_air()
  returns trigger 
 language plpgsql 
as $$
begin 
    update products 
       set reviews = reviews+1
     where prod_id = new.prod_id;
    return new;
end;
$$;

create trigger reviews_air
         after insert 
           on reviews
          for each row 
          execute function record_a_review_air();
```

NOTE: Setting a DEFAULT will not accomplish what you want. Doing so would set the a value when the Product is inserted. But would never be invoked again for that Product.